# RoR rails generate rspec:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, rspec

Hi all I am a newbie in RoR and I've just started...

when i typed rails generate rspec:install, they gave me an error: 'mkdir':Invalid argument - ./C: (Errno::EINVAL), and a lot more errors at the bottom.

The following is my Gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc


gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]

gem "rspec-support",        :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-support.git"

gem "rspec-rails",        :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.git"

gem "rspec",              :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec.git"

gem "rspec-core",         :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-core.git"

gem "rspec-expectations", :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations.git"

gem "rspec-mocks",        :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks.git"
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using the git version of these gems (rather than just gem "rspec-rails"). Using a non release version does make it more likely you'll run into corner cases.

Comment: Hi @frederick, i have no idea what is the difference... i've followed through some stack overflow questions and those few lines helped me solved issues. I couldn't even find rspec initially when i had just rspec rails...

Answer (score 2):

I have been getting the same error message - looks like this is a recurring problem with the newest versions of rspec not playing well with Windows (most recently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25860824/3344666). In case anyone finds themselves here with the same problem in newer versions:

Without specifying a version number, 3.1.0 was installed and did not work correctly. I specified an earlier version of rspec-rails '~> 3.0.0' in my gemfile and can attest to that version running rpec:install correctly. In the end I had to go down to '2.14.1' to get everything working as planned.

They're working on it: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-support/pull/109

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I verify that what Penelope said was correct. Using 'rspec-rails', '2.14.1' solve the problem. However, there was one more step which I have to do to make it work after changing version. This step is from this answer 
[rspec --init not working/ `mkd ir': Invalid argument - ./C: (Errno::EINVAL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858155/rspec-init-not-working-mkd-ir-invalid-argument-c-errnoeinval)

Bascially, you need to run this command in your cmd/terminal after you change the version in your gemfile.

```
gem uninstall rspec
gem uninstall rspec-core rspec-expectations rspec-mocks rspec-support
gem install rspec -v 2.14.1
bundle install
```

Thereafter, try this again.

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

It should work.