# rspec --init not working/ `mkd ir': Invalid argument - ./C: (Errno::EINVAL)

Tags: ruby, powershell, rspec, rubygems, init

I'm following codeschool's [class on rspec](http://rspec.codeschool.com/levels/1). Installing worked fine. I made a file called rspec-zombie for the project. Fine. But when I tried rspec --init in powershell, I got an unholy error message. I'm under the impression there are supposed to be some files made inside the directory, which aren't there. It follows.

```
C:\Users\Roman\The-Odin-Project\rspec-zombie> rspec --init
  create   .rspec
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-support-3.1.0/lib/rspec/support/directory_maker.rb:17:in `mkd
ir': Invalid argument - ./C: (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-support-3.1.0/lib/rspec/support/directory_maker.
rb:17:in `block in mkdir_p'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-support-3.1.0/lib/rspec/support/directory_maker.
rb:13:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-support-3.1.0/lib/rspec/support/directory_maker.
rb:13:in `mkdir_p'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/lib/rspec/core/project_initializer.rb
:33:in `copy_template'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/lib/rspec/core/project_initializer.rb
:22:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/lib/rspec/core/option_parser.rb:81:in
 `block (2 levels) in parser'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1360:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1360:in `block in parse_in_order'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1347:in `catch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1347:in `parse_in_order'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1341:in `order!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1432:in `permute!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1453:in `parse!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/lib/rspec/core/option_parser.rb:16:in
 `parse'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/lib/rspec/core/option_parser.rb:8:in
`parse'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.
rb:120:in `command_line_options'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.
rb:154:in `custom_options_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.
rb:112:in `file_options'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.
rb:44:in `organize_options'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.
rb:14:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:58:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:58:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invok
e'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Is the command you are trying to execute `rspec --init` or `rspec --init create .rspec`. I'm not sure from the code provided

Comment: create rspec was printed to the console after I typed the command "rspec --init" So, rspec --init.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I finally fixed this crap:

```
gem uninstall rspec
gem uninstall rspec-core rspec-expectations rspec-mocks rspec-support
gem install rspec -v 2.14.1
```

Basically, newer versions of rspec are broken on Windows. Don't use them. Do this and rspec works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a windows regression in RSpec 3.1 that we are working on:

- <del>https://github.com/rspec/rspec-support/issues/107</del>
- <del>https://github.com/rspec/rspec-support/pull/109</del>

Above issues were fixed.

Comment: I'm glad. Would it be too much to ask if you could update this post when the fix is complete? Thanks.

Comment: I'll likely forget, to be honest.  I'd encourage you to subscribe to the github issues (see the button under "Notifications" on the side) if you want notification when they are resolved.